# Projection of a vector in $L^2[0,1]$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a closed subspace of $L^2[0,1]$ and let $f,g \in L^2[0,1] $ be given by $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^2$. If $V^{\perp}= span (f)$ and $Pg$ is the orthogonal projection of $g$ on $V$, then $(g-Pg)(x)$, $x \in [0,1]$ is

(A)$\frac{3x}{4}$ (B) $\frac{x}{4}$ (C) $\frac{3x^2}{4}$ (D) $\frac{x^2}{4}$

The value is actually the projection of $x^2$ on $V^{\perp}$. But I dont know how to solve this. Can someone help me please?

Comment: I don't see how $f$ comes into play. Is the definition of $Pg$ right?

Comment: $f=x$ and $Pg$ is the projection of $g$ on $V$

Comment: Which scalar product is used here? The standart $\langle a,b\rangle = \int\limits^1_0 a b dx$?

Comment: Yes, the standard one

Answer (score 4):

If $P$ is projection on $M$ then  $I-P$ is the projection on  $M^{\perp}$. Hence you are just asked to find the projection on span of $f$ which is $\frac {\langle f, g \rangle} {\|f\|^{2}} f$. The correct answer is (A).

Comment: thank you very much sir for your kind support